# jQuery: use of wrap() on <img> element 

Tags: jquery

html:

```
<img src="http://webmuseum.mit.edu/mobiusicons/no_image.jpg" />
```

css:

```
div.border
{
border: 2px solid #ccc;
width: 500px;
height: 500px;
}
```

js:

```
$("img").wrap('<div class="border" />');
```

This is my first time using the jquery `wrap()`. I was expecting to see the following

```
<div class="border"><img src="http://webmuseum.mit.edu/mobiusicons/no_image.jpg" /></div>
```

but `wrap()` didn't change anything and I got no error. Please help. Thanks.

Comment: That should work fine.. Make sure that you have included jquery.js file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is working absolutely fine for me.  See http://jsfiddle.net/trott/9Nm3M/.

(Try changing the border thickness to 20px for confirmation if you're not sure that it's working.)

Perhaps you aren't loading jQuery or something like that?

Comment: Thx for confirming my code for me. It was a typo in my original code.

Answer (score 1):

Have you included `<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>` in your head section. 
Check where it is loaded or not.. 
follow these:
 http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials:Getting_Started_with_jQuery
http://docs.jquery.com/Downloading_jQuery

check this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/niranjankala/auHX2/)  and it is working correct with your code..

Comment: Thx for confirming my code for me. It was a typo in my original code.